# Plotting linear regression and residual in Maxima via gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, maxima, texmacs

### Motivation

I'm using [TeXmacs](https://www.texmacs.org/) to write math assignments and [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/documentation.html) as CAS program. I recently found out how to use `plot2d` in [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) via Maxima.

### Questions

1. I now need to plot a linear regression line using some coordinates / table data.
2. And it would be nice to be able to get the linear regression function `f(x) = mx+b` or `f(x) = a+bx` from the same data. *Nice to have - not required.*
3. I also need to draw a residual plot from the same data. Perhaps getting the `r^2` value.

### Researched

I have read https://stackoverflow.com/a/9077851/205696 which answers how to draw a regression line in gnuplot but I do not know how to port that to the [`plot2d` function in Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_64.html#plot2d).

I also read [this Q/A that explains how to calculate the equation for linear regression with Maxima](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50241780/205696) but I am frankly not good enough in math to understand what is actually going on.

I found out that I can [plot linear regressions with GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/zadxwktb), but I do not see a way to draw a residual plot or to get `f(x) = mx+b` on the data I have provided (I can calculate `f(x) = ax+b` from observation but it would be nice to get exact numbers).

### Explanatory images

[image: Data table and linear regression line in TI Nspire]
*Data table and linear regression line in TI Nspire.*

[image: Data table, linear regression line and residual plot in TI Nspire]
*Data table, linear regression line and residual plot in TI Nspire.*

[image: Statistical calculations -> Linear regression in TI Nspire]
*Statistical calculations -> Linear regression in TI Nspire.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a solution. There is a function `linear_regression` in the `stats` package which does most of the work.

Let `x` and `y` be two lists, which contain your data. `linear_regression` expects a matrix of two or more columns. To paste the lists together into a matrix, you can say: `xy: addcol(matrix(), x, y);` (There are other ways to do it.)

To get an object which contains the coefficients and residuals and other items, you can say: `results: linear_regression(xy);`

To get the residuals: `myresiduals: take_inference('residuals, results);`

To get the coefficients: `coeffs: take_inference('b_estimation, results);`

Now with the coefficients, you can construct a function to represent the regression line: `myline: subst(['b = coeffs[1], 'm = coeffs[2]], lambda([x], m*x + b));`

(Be sure to check the coefficients -- I might have gotten them reversed. Maybe it's `coeffs[2]` and then `coeffs[1]`? You should check.)

At this point you have `x`, `y`, `residuals`, and `myline`. Plot them all together:

```
plot2d ([[discrete, x, y], [discrete, x, residuals], myline], ['x, lmin(x) - 1, lmax(x) + 1]);
```

To get more info, see: `? linear_regression`

Comment: Thanks! Still trying to trying to get this to work. I'm wondering if there is also a `exponential_regression` function? I can't find it in [the list of Maxima functions](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_377.html#Function-and-Variable-Index)

Comment: `nth_root` is also very welcome, so I can calculate the constants when two points are known.

Comment: Nevermind about `nth_root` - I found a working implementation https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root#Maxima

Comment: There isn't an exponential regression function, but I think you can get the same effect by taking the logarithm of the data (dunno whether you want log(x) and log(y), or only one or the other) and then applying linear regression. About nth root, `sqrt(x)` is the square root, and `x^(1/n)` is the nth root.

Comment: hehe I finally got it! I did not know that I had to `load (stats);` first. I thought it was built-in when I saw the documentation. I actually got that from chatGPT - the only thing it got right :)